# How to specify the value of pressure in a point in solving steady stokes equation numerically?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, navier-stokes

I try to solve the steady-Stokes equation numerically on , that is
\begin{aligned}
-\nabla \cdot \mathbb{T}(\mathbf{u}, p) & =\mathbf{f} \quad \text { on } \Omega=[0,1]*[-0.25,0], \\
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} & =0 \quad \text { in } \Omega, \\
u_1 & =e^{-y} \text { on } x=0, \\
u_1 & =y^2+e^{-y} \text { on } x=1, \\
u_1 & =\frac{1}{16} x^2+e^{0.25} \text { on } y=-0.25, \\
u_1 & =1 \text { on } y=0 \\
u_2 & =2 \text { on } x=0 \\
u_2 & =-\frac{2}{3} y^3+2 \text { on } x=1, \\
u_2 & =\frac{1}{96} x+2-\pi \sin (\pi x) \text { on } y=-0.25, \\
u_2 & =2-\pi \sin (\pi x) \text { on } y=0 .
\end{aligned}
here \begin{aligned}
& f_1=-2 \nu x^2-2 \nu y^2-\nu e^{-y}+\pi^2 \cos (\pi x) \cos (2 \pi y) \\
& f_2=4 \nu x y-\nu \pi^3 \sin (\pi x)+2 \pi(2-\pi \sin (\pi x)) \sin (2 \pi y)
\end{aligned}
here the $T$ is $$
\mathbb{T}(\mathbf{u}, p)=2 \nu \mathbb{D}(\mathbf{u})-p \mathbb{I}
$$
where $\nu$ is the viscosity and the deformation tensor
$$
\mathbb{D}(\mathbf{u})=\frac{1}{2}\left(\nabla \mathbf{u}+(\nabla \mathbf{u})^t\right)
$$
and the analytical solution is
\begin{aligned}
& u_1=x^2 y^2+e^{-y}, \quad u_2=-\frac{2}{3} x y^3+2-\pi \sin (\pi x) \\
& p=-(2-\pi \sin (\pi x)) \cos (2 \pi y)
\end{aligned}
the procedure of solving this equation numerically is provided by my teacher by using Taylor-hood finite element method,that is

- Generate the mesh information matrices $P$ and $T$.
- Assemble the stiffness matrix $A$ by using Algorithm I. (We will choose Algorithm I-3 in class)
- Assemble the load vector $\vec{b}$ by using Algorithm II. (We will choose Algorithm II-3 in class)
- Deal with the Dirichlet boundary condition by using Algorithm III-3.
- Fix the pressure at one point in the domain $\Omega$.
- Solve $A \vec{X}=\vec{b}$ for $\vec{X}$ by using a direct or iterative method.
  after dealing with the Dirichlet boundary condition, I wonder how to fix the value of pressure at a point? I try to fix the value at the first node by eatablishin in the following way:

  $A(2*N_b+1,:)=0;\\
  A(2*N_b+1,2*N_b+1)=1;\\
  b(2*N_b+1,1)=0;\\\\$
  here $N_b$ is the number of total basis of quadratic element, is this right?

Comment: "Is this right?" -- What happens when you try?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth  the inf norm of error diverge, the inf error of p is large and the inf error of u is relatively small but it is still not convergent

Comment: So if you subtract the mean value from the pressure after the linear solve, is the error in the pressure then still large?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth could you please tell me what is the meaning of "subtract the mean value from the pressure after the linear solve" I kind of don't understand it

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I fix this, an error occured while dealing with dirichlet boundary condition, the if condition in the construction of boundarynodes is wrong